# Debug: PHP MySQL Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement, bindparam

What I am trying to do is, to prepare and bind the `SELECT` query using placeholders, however there is an error.

My Codes:

```
$stmt = $connection->prepare("SELECT `ID`, `booking`.`flightDestination`, `flightTime`, `typeOfFlight`, `flightDate` FROM `booking` JOIN `flight` ON `booking`.`ID` = `flight`.`flightNo` WHERE `booking`.`flightDestination` = '?' AND `flightDate` = '?' AND `typeOfFlight` = '?'");
if(!$stmt){
    echo "Prepare statement error";
    echo $connection->error;
}
$stmt->bind_param("sss",$flightDestination,$flightDate,$typeOfFlight); //binds the parameter $token as string
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$NOR = $stmt->num_rows;
$stmt->bind_result($getID,$getFlightDestination,$getFlightTime,$getTypeOfFlight,$getFlightDate);
```

I found that my prepare statement contains 3 placeholders, and in my `bind_param()` contains exactly 3 variables.

However the output is

> Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement in C:\xampp\htdocs\B-Flight\flightSearch.php on line 76
>   **Destination   Type    Date    Flight No   Departure Time  Period**

Am wondering, `bind_param()` only binds the 3 variables with the 3 placeholders, why did it even mention about the other variables?

Comment: `'?'` those are the problem. Consult the duplicate this was closed with.

Comment: remove "."  after booking and replace with ","

Comment: @Fred-ii- the problem is not that he have a period instead of a commo in the query

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile Nope. Fred is right. `<table>.<column>` is valid syntax.

Comment: yes and that period after booking is adding to the problem

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile Again. No, it's not.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thanks for the help. I read that post before, didnt notice on the ' ' on the ? shouldn't have included

Comment: @user7008 You're welcome.

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile my table name `booking` and I am trying to access the column name `flightDestination` and `ID`, therefore I uses  booking.flightDestination with backquote and it worked as Jon said

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile See for yourself by consulting the official (MySQL) documentation http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html

Comment: Oh I see I thought that booking was a column, @Fred-ii- sorry man,... there's no consistency in the code thats why I did not notice that

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile No problemo, *cheers*. We're all here to learn and I myself do continue to learn; it's never done, it only gets better ;-)